# How to print an array till there are values.Not the full array?

Tags: java

I have declared an array a of type int with size 100.After some operations that array contain some values.All the 100 positions doesn't have values.So How to print array till it has values?My code is bellow.But it will print all the array.please help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner inp=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,i,j;
        int arr[]=new int[100];
        System.out.println("Enter the limit");
        a=inp.nextInt();
        j=0;
        for(i=2;i<a;i++)
        {
            if((i%2)==0)
            {
                arr[j]=i;
                j++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even numbers till " +a);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

### output is

Enter the limit
25

Even numbers till 25
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 .... 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print a prefix of the array by copying a part of the array into a new array :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(arr,j)));
```

The alternative is to iterate over the elements of the array and print them yourself until you reach the last index you wish to print.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the sentence below in your code:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

then replace to:

```
for( i = 0; i < j; i ++ )
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
```